# Jest won´t complete my async function for my api call function

Tags: typescript, react-native, asynchronous, async-await, jestjs

I´m working on a small app that uses an API. I want to make a test to see that the function works as intended. The function works, but in the test, the function will not complete and therefore fail. I´ve looked here on stack overflow and on youtube for hours and I still do not get it to work.

Here is my test case:

```
import * as API from './geonames';


test('Get the country code from sweden', async () => {
    
    
    return API.getCountryCode("Sweden").then(res => console.log(res));
    
    
}, 5000);
```

And here is my function:

```
export async function getCountryCode(country: string): Promise<any> {
    // uses the ninja API to get the country code
    var url = 'https://api.api-ninjas.com/v1/country?name=' + country;
    try {
        console.log("Before res"); // this runs in my test
        let res = await fetch(url, { headers: {'X-Api-Key': API_NINJA_KEY}});
        console.log("After res"); // this does not run in my test
        let data = await res.json();
        console.log("After data")
        var countryCode = data[0]['iso2'];
    
        return countryCode
    } catch (e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: In `getCountryCode()` is the `After data` actually logged?.

Comment: In the test case, no

Comment: Did you figure it out? Did the answer help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is the `fetch()` function.  On Clientside it exists (in browser) but on `nodejs` it does not exist. Since you added a `try/catch` block the error is *silently* omitted.

First of, log the error!!, It is really dangerous to **NOT** log an error. Usually prefer to log it anywhere as long as you are in development environment.

```js
export async function getCountryCode(country: string): Promise<any> {
    // uses the ninja API to get the country code
    var url = 'https://api.api-ninjas.com/v1/country?name=' + country;
    try {
        console.log("Before res"); // this runs in my test
        let res = await fetch(url, { headers: {'X-Api-Key': API_NINJA_KEY}});
        console.log("After res"); // this does not run in my test
        let data = await res.json();
        console.log("After data")
        var countryCode = data[0]['iso2'];
    
        return countryCode
    } catch (e) {
        /// Always log or throw an error, never silent!!
        console.error('GetCountryCode() failed..', e)
    }
}
```

### solution

You need to use some other library for fetching in the tests. So for making the `getCountryCode()` working in browser and code ideally create a helper function for getting correct request. I suggest even to create a general request function which you use always.

For example:

```
// Use any module on serverside you want. I suggest axios
import axios from 'axios'

// Always run all http requests over this function
// The function decides which implementation to use.
const get_requester = () => {
    // if fetch present, return it!
    if (window && typeof fetch === 'function') {
        return fetch
    }

    return axios


}

const requestApi = (url: string, opts: Object) => {
    const request = get_requester()

    // do request.. You may need to modify a little
    request(url, opts)

}
```

And then in `getCountryCode()` use it like:

```
// ... import request
export async function getCountryCode(country: string): Promise<any> {
    // uses the ninja API to get the country code
    var url = 'https://api.api-ninjas.com/v1/country?name=' + country;
    try {
        console.log("Before res"); // this runs in my test
        // make use of request api
        let res = await requestApi(url, { 
            headers: {'X-Api-Key': API_NINJA_KEY}, 
             method: 'GET' 
        });
        console.log("After res"); // this does not run in my test
        let data = await res.json();
        console.log("After data")
        var countryCode = data[0]['iso2'];
    
        return countryCode
    } catch (e) {

    }
}
```